# How To Shuffle Number In C++

Tags: c++, random, shuffle

I have number form 1-42
I want to let C++ shuffle number for me, I have number form 1-42 and I used code below :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
int S[42]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42};
random_shuffle(&S[1], &S[42]);
cout<<S[42];
}
```

It's working, but the problem is every times i run it, it always show number 3 all the time, I think there is something wrong,
Please help;

Comment: Call `std::srand`, or better yet don't use `random_shuffle` if you have access to c++11 and beyond.

Comment: don't you have to initialize random differently ? random generators always yield the same sequence at the start of the program unless you initialize it with system time for instance.

Comment: @StoryTeller Better not depend on `std::rand()`, nor `std::random_shuffle` using `std::rand()`. `std::shuffle` with a RNG from [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) is superior.

Comment: @Hengly, consider googling about it. You need to provide a seed to the random number generator, and if you provide the same seed every time, you'd get the same results.

Comment: Seeding for RNG from `<random>`: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/109260/seed-stdmt19937-from-stdrandom-device

Comment: BTW: `cout<<S[42];` is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Well, thank for replying, at that time I was a beginner at C++.

Comment: I came back again to see this post, It reminds of how stupid I was, but anyway it was fun, guys!